# Deploy To tomcat7 without restarting server

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, amazon-ec2, application-server

I am creating a `maven3`, `tomcat7`, `Spring4` java web app. I have my app deployed on an `Amazon AWS Ec2` instance. My current work flow is as follows

1. Make changes in my local environment.
2. `git push` my changes to my bitbucket account.
3. `ssh` into my Ec2 instance.
4. `git pull` my changes down from bitbucket.
5. `kill -9` the current tomcat process running on the Ec2
6. Run `mvn clean tomcat7:run` on my Ec2 to restart the server so the changes are applied.

The server runs on port 8080, and I have set up the iptables to forward port 80 to 8080. This is all working well.

However, when it comes to deploying a tomcat/maven app, I am a noob. So here are my questions:

Is this the best way to run my java web application? Should `mvn install` or `mvn deploy` be part of the process somewhere?

In many tutorials I see references to a `server.xml` to configure tomcat, and as far as I know, I don't have a server.xml file because tomcat is configured completely by maven using the tomcat7 plugin. Is that a problem?

And lastly, how can I make changes to my live server (the Ec2 instance) without having to restart tomcat? When my app is live server down time will not be acceptable.

I am just kind of looking for a general explanatory answer of how this process works in the real-world so I can know if I am doing it correctly.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can still configure the settings of tomcat7 in the ~/.m2/.settings.xml folder and add some setting such as:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>TomcatServer</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

I don't know how you can make live change from a maven tomcat7:run command, but you can install a native version for tomcat via a package manager, so you just have to drop the .war in the `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps` folder(this path may change on some linux distribution). Then you can remove and drop a new .war at anytime without rebooting the tomcat7 service.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy in tomcat through the API.

1. Edit %TOMCAT_HOME%/conf/tomcat_users.xml Your file should looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/eddumelendez/a0759e4ed10a9c3fa890#file-tomcat_users-xml).
2. Edit %USER_HOME%/.m2/settings.xml Your file should looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/eddumelendez/a0759e4ed10a9c3fa890#file-settings-xml)
3. In your pom.xml add the following [plugin](https://gist.github.com/eddumelendez/a0759e4ed10a9c3fa890#file-pom-xml).

So, in your AWS instance you need to have a tomcat server running.